# Searching a deeply nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I have a deep nested ragged list.

```
list= {{{
        {{0}, 13}, {{1}, 15}, {{0, 0}, 12}, {{1, 1}, 9}, … , 
        {{0}, 3}, {{1}, 5}, {{0, 0}, 2}, {{1, 1}, 19}, … 
       }}}
```

The list is the result of obtaining a `Tally` around a string of 0s and 1s that has been `Split` to identify runs.

I am interested in finding all of the occurrences of say `{0, 0}` from the nested list. I tried Position

```
Position[list, {0, 0}]
```

It works fine and I get:

> ```
> {{1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 1}, …
> ```

However, I wanted to use `Select` or `Cases` to pull out the elements that contained the element of interest. I've tried to follow some examples at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893090/selectnested-list-condition-in-mathematica.

For example, I tried:

```
   Select[list, #[[_, _, _, y_]] == {0, 0} &]
   Cases[list, {_, _, _, y_} /; y == {0, 0}]
```

However, I was unsuccessful. I suspect that I am not defining the depth for the search as a proper list.

Comment: `Cases[list, {0, 0}, Infinity]`?

Comment: @Muralli, you may also want to see `Extract`, as `Extract[list, Position[list, {0, 0}]]`

Comment: Murally, please include a more representative example of your list. If too big, use pastebin or a similar service to post the whole list. Also, when you say that you want to extract the elements that contain `{0, 0}`, do you mean the immediately enclosing list?

Comment: `Cases[list, {{0, 0}, _}, ∞]`

Comment: @m_goldberg: {0,0} is an example of the pattern I am searching for in the ragged nested list. It is a vector list itself. I am going to see if I post the list on pastern. Will let you know when I do.

Comment: @MarcoB: A representative 3 x 4 list is now at http://pastebin.com/TnRRc9Gq.  My real dataset is 73 x 2000.

Comment: Cases[list, {{0, 0}, _}, ∞] worked. Thanks everyone.